# PHPUnit Selenium2 Cannot Find Tag on tests

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'm working on testing a site with PHPUnit (3.7.38), Selenium2 (2.43.1-standalone) and Firefox (34.0), and keep running into an intermittent problem with Selenium not being able to find tags on a page.  If I take a screenshot of the error, the tag and content is there and the page looks as if it is fully loaded.  There really is no AJAX to speak of on the tags I'm trying to load that would cause issue.

This seems to happen about 50% of the time and in a few specific tests.  As well, it seems to gravitate towards specific lines of the test, but usually will change lines if I comment out the offending line.  If I wait several minutes between tests it seems to run without error, but other than that I can't find anything that affects it.

The specific exception is:

`PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"h2"}`

Selenium Trace:

```
22:32:34.544 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.tagName: h2])
22:32:35.704 WARN - Exception thrown org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"h2"}
Command duration or timeout: 220 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
System info: host: 'andrew-xubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-43-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Session ID: e842f08c-176e-4361-859b-8fc8e67b8d5c
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=34.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByTagName(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElement(By.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.findElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"h2"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
System info: host: 'andrew-xubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch:  'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-43-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///tmp   /anonymous8627931668853884881webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9618:26)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///tmp/anonymous8627931668853884881webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9627:3)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///tmp/anonymous8627931668853884881webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11612:16)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///tmp/anonymous8627931668853884881webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11617:7)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///tmp/anonymous8627931668853884881webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11559:5)
22:32:35.706 WARN - Exception: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"h2"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
System info: host: 'andrew-xubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-43-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like upping the time Selenium waits to find elements fixed it.  Adding this code to each test increases the time for each time Selenium loads a page.

```
function setUpPage() {
        $this->timeouts ()->implicitWait ( 3000 );
}
```